# Bash prompt goes horizontal, after executing parent shell script which spawns multiple process

Tags: shell

I have a parent shell script, say parent.sh. This script will spawn 5 child process and I am using wait command for all child process to execute.

But after successful execution, my bash prompt goes horizontal when typing enter. After typing reset, bash prompt comes to normal.

Please suggest me, what is the reason for this.

bash-4.1$ sh parent.sh

executing child1.sh

executing child2.sh

executing child3.sh

executing child4.sh

executing child5.sh

successfully executed

bash-4.1$ bash-4.1$ bash-4.1$ bash-4.1$ bash-4.1$ bash-4.1$ bash-4.1$ bash-4.1$ bash-4.1$ bash-4.1$ bash-4.1$ bash-4.1$ bash-4.1$ bash-4.1$

Comment: Do you mean "horizontal"? What do the scripts do?

Comment: Sorry it is horizontal. Child scripts are basically, the same parent script called multiple times for parallel execution. Script will update the data in hive tables.

Comment: They apparently do something to the terminal. Please reduce the problem as far as possible and then show all the code.